# CBPeripheralManager read/write

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I'm using CoreBluetooth on the iPhone and I'm wondering if there's a way to do read/write requests from the peripheral side.  I have set up a CBPeripheralManager and a delegate, but looking through the documentation I don't see any way to read from a peripheral's attributes or even its own attributes.

Is this only possible from Central?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. CoreBluetooth assumes that if you're setting up a peripheral, you wouldn't query the Bluetooth stack to retrieve attributes about yourself, and instead would simply query some internal data structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to send data from a `CBPeripheralManager` to one or more connected `CBCentral`s, use a characteristic that has notify or indicate enabled. The `CBPeripheralManager` can send data like so:

```
let success = peripheralManager.updateValue(data, forCharacteristic: characteristic,
    onSubscribedCentrals: [central])
if !success {
    // cache the data until the delegate method peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers is called.
}
```

Note: Make sure the `CBCentral`s subscribe to the characteristic you plan on using.

As for reading data from a `CBCentral`, you could send a "read request" using the method above, and have the `CBCentral` respond with the data you're looking for.